# REST API invocation in Java

Tags: java, rest, url, io, httpclient

Suppose I need to write a Java client, which calls a REST API (with HTTP GET). I know it returns the data in JSON by default and I do not need to supply any headers.

Now I can use *either* Apache `HttpClient` to invoke the API *or* read the URL directly (get a stream from the URL with `url.openStream` and read the data). The second approach seems to me much simpler. Which one would you suggest and why ?

Comment: I would use any Java REST anyway. it is my personal recommendation.

Answer (score 1):

All the REST clients provide a wrapper over basic java URL based APIs. These clients are easy to use and provide all the necessary functionality. Your code will be much cleaner in case you use Apache HttpClient. And Apache's API are quite reliable.

Answer (score 1):

I would use special libraries for that, like Jersey client or Apache CXF client.
https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/client.html
http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs.html

These ones are part of Java EE standard, a well defined specification which is widely used.

For JSON, consider https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson. Depending on what client you use, you will find information about how to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not a big fan of JavaEE, and you look for neat and elegant API, and you are interested in working with a language on top of Java, [Groovy HTTPBuilder](http://groovy.codehaus.org/modules/http-builder/doc/rest.html) is such a library that works like a charm!

```
twitter = new RESTClient( 'https://twitter.com/statuses/' )
resp = twitter.post( path : 'update.xml',
                 body : [ status:msg, source:'httpbuilder' ],
                 requestContentType : URLENC )
assert resp.status == 200
assert resp.data.user.screen_name == userName
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use spring-data-rest and Spring's RestTemplate. No need to write a webapp as you can bootstrap Spring easily into a standalone java application putting `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext` in the Main(). It's quite simple.

For example, suppose you have a Restful URL, `http://localhost:8080/croot/books/` that returns a list of books (deserialized into objects of type Book).

Using Spring's RestTemplate you can do the following:

```
public Resource<List<Resource<Book>>> findAll() {

        return restTemplate
                .exchange(
                        "http://localhost:8080/croot/books/",
                        HttpMethod.GET,
                        null,
                        new ParameterizedTypeReference<Resource<List<Resource<Book>>>>() {
                        }).getBody();
}
```

You can also process this using spring-data-hateoas allowing you to further decouple the client from the server and helps process what to do next, say in pagination.

This is a very simplified/contrived example but the REST support in Spring 3 combined with the spring-data framework is quite elegant.

Using Spring you also get the advantage of Jackson for JSON processing as the `RestTemplate` will have one of the flavors of Jackson's message converters (provided through `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` for example) in it's list of default converters used for processing.